# How is "しかい" used in this sentence?

Tags: translation, meaning, particle-しか

I'm a bit confused about how "しかい" is used in this sentence I came across while studying:

そこには私一人**しかい**なかった。
"I was the only one there."

My guess is that it is an ending to "一人", but I couldn't find any information supporting that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's actually the particle `しか` "nothing but/nobody but" plus `いなかった`, the negative past form of `いる` "to be/to exist" (animate).  Your translation is right.  It means "I was the only one there".

The particle `しか` is always paired with negative verbs like this.  Taking an example from *A Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar* (p.401):

> ボブ**しか**[来]{こ}なかった。
>   Nobody but Bob came. = Only Bob came.

The particle `しか` works the same way in your example.